# Betrayal at house on the hill haunt #13 (Spoilers)

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Me and the family bought the second edition of the game and from what we've played it's fun but.. but I'm so confused as to what tokens to use or how to set up the haunt. Is one of the players asleep? Or do we us a token? If it's a player and they are asleep and we have the pickpocket gloves can we steal from them? It's doesn't specifically say. Any help would be appreciated. Also what do we do with the tokens it says to use (e.g the triangular ones)

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: I am going off of the first edition rules, as that is all I have access to. It's possible there are updates in the second edition for this haunt that I am not aware of.*

The traitor's character is the one that falls asleep. This is described in the Traitor's Tome rulebook:

> **Right Now**
>
> > Tip your figure over in the room it's in when the
> >     haunt is revealed. Your body is asleep. You can't
> >     move or take any actions. Drop all of your items.

This character cannot do anything for the rest of the game. So on the Traitor's turns, they just take the actions for their monsters.

The traitor will also drop all items when the haunt begins, so there will never be a chance to steal from them. Items that are dropped just sit on the floor of the room where they were dropped, and can be picked up by anyone who goes into that room.

For the tokens, the Traitor needs a set of nightmare tokens and a set of escape room tokens. In the first edition, there were specific "nightmare" tokens; in the second edition monster tokens are more generic, so you use any monster token. For the escape room tokens, they can be any token; it doesn't matter so long as they are all the same:

> Set aside a number of "escape tokens" equal to
>   the number of escape rooms in the house. (Any
>   distinctive set of tokens, such as Rat or Blob
>   tokens, will do.)

The triangular tokens are just a way to count how many times you have succeeded in the action of trying to wake the dreamer. Each time you successfully roll a 5+ to wake the dreamer, you take a triangular token to mark that you have succeeded. Having you set aside the triangular tokens during setup is just because you will need them during the game; it's not actually important how many you set aside, or even which types. It tells you to take a might token when you succeed with might, and a sanity token when you succeed with sanity, but this doesn't matter; you just take a token to track that you have succeeded.

Unfortunately this game is infamous for having issues with the rules being unclear or confusing sometimes; even the second edition with its updates to the rules didn't fix everything. Having you use separate might vs sanity tokens for the triangular tokens just seems like a case of the game choosing to be more thematic rather than simple or clear.